# How to fread into a vector inside a class?

Tags: c++

```
class WavFile
{
    std::vector<short> SoundData;

public:

    std::vector<short> getSoundData()
    {
        return SoundData;
    }
}
```

Normally I'd use `fread( &SoundData[0], 1, 1337, SomeFile );`

But now that I'm using a vector inside a class, I'm having trouble with the following:

- Knowing how to set the vector size outside the class.
- And I'm not sure how to use the method as an argument for `fread` to put the data inside the vector.

Comment: I'm don't know why you need to resize the vector outside of the class, but for reading the file into your vector, you can use `std::istream_iterator` coupled to `std::copy` (found in headers iostream / algorithm)

Comment: @Jean-MarieComets Because if I don't fread() won't write into the vector. I'm a newbie so I haven't looked into the istream_iterator method. Care to show a sample of what that'd look like?

Comment: Check out [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=67867) page for more information.

Comment: @Jean-MarieComets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665534/getting-desired-binary-data-ranges-from-stdistreambuf-iterator-and-stdifstre This is why I don't use std::istream_iterator btw.

Comment: @Jean-MarieComets Since I can't use `std::copy` for the above reason. I have to use `fstream::read`, which means I have to set the size of the vector outside of the class before I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is **bad** in general. There are some main points to it:

If you are encapsulating `vector` in class, you can still operate on it normally from the outside if it's public.

```
WavFile WF;
void* Ptr = WF.SoundData.data();
// void* Ptr = &WF.SoundData[0]; - C++03
```

You can also *wrap* some of the calls to the vector, `.resize()` for example:

```
void WavFile::resize(vector::size_type new_size) {
    SoundData.resize(new_size);
}

void* WavFile::getRawPtr () {
    return SoundData.data();
    // return (&SoundData[0]); - C++03
}
```

If you are using `std::vector`, you should also use corresponding C++ read functions on it. Treating `vector` as a memory array is valid, but there are better ways to use it, `fstream` for example.

If you are encapsulating `vector` (or any `std` container in general), don't return it by value! It will cause all of the elements to be copied. Instead, return a const-reference to container, or, even better, range.

Comment: Well first, thank you so much. I knew of resize it just never hit me to use it (newbie woes). Still, would probably have not figured out to use it as an argument to a method. As for the last points, fread only accepts pointer as an argument so I wasn't going to return the value in the end it was just an example.

Comment: One small question, is it ok to return it by value if I don't want to implement a wrapper when I want to do something like  `WF.getSoundDataVector().size()`?

Comment: No, since still all of the elements will be copied to a temporary, and then the `.size()` will be called. Returning by reference is just adding `const&` to return type, nothing else! And if you want to check which functions are accessible by const object, you can look in lang. reference. Anyway, as I said, you should probably return `range` for reading, it's more general (i.e. you can change inner container without affecting code that's using your class).

Comment: And just one more thing, @Tek. Don't use `short` type, unless you are perfectly sure you need 16-bit type (using other library, perhaps). And if you need to use it that way, mark it explicitly by `typedef short int16;` or `using int16 = short;`. `short` size isn't constant, and it's not sensible to use it for arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

> - Knowing how to set the vector size outside the class.

You can construct the vector passing the size to the vector's constructor.

> - And I'm not sure how to use the method as an argument for fread to put the data inside the vector.

Why are you using `fread` to begin with? Why not `fstream`?

Also, once you initialize the vector passing the size, you can use `&v[0]` just as you would use if it was declared as c-array (i.e `float v[const_size]`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665534/getting-desired-binary-data-ranges-from-stdistreambuf-iterator-and-stdifstre This is why I don't use fstream.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use vector as argument to fread. You have to allocate a block of memory (short buffer[SIZE]) as buffer to read data in, then insert data element by element to vector from the buffer.

Although fread is allowed in C++, it's better to use native C++ way to read file, such as fstream.

Comment: Since everyone suggested `fstream`, this is why I didn't use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665534/getting-desired-binary-data-ranges-from-stdistreambuf-iterator-and-stdifstre