# C++ binary files and iterators: getting away with a 1:1 using ifstreambuf_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, iterator, fstream

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665583/2485710) points out the fact that C++ is not well suited for the iteration over a binary file, but this is what I need right now, in short I need to operate on files in a "binary" way, yes all files are binary even the .txt ones, but I'm writing something that operates on image files, so I need to read files that are well structured, were the data is arranged in a specific way.

I would like to read the entire file in a data structure such as `std::vector<T>` so I can almost immediately close the file and work with the content in memory without caring about disk I/O anymore.

Right now, the best way to perform a complete iteration over a file according to the standard library is something along the lines of

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
  for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > it(ifs.rdbuf());
       it != std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >(); it++) {
    // do something with *it;
  }
ifs.close();
```

or use `std::copy`, but even with `std::copy` you are always using `istreambuf` iterators ( so if I understand the C++ documentation correctly, you are basically reading 1 byte at each call with the previous code ).

So the question is: how do I write a custom iterator ? from where I should inherit from ?

I assume that this is also important while writing a file to disk, and I assume that I could use the same iterator class for writing, if I'm wrong please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Is the *size* of the inbound data precluding you from just [`ifs.read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)-ing the data straight up into a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and iterating over that?

Comment: @WhozCraig for now I don't think that the file are too big to be kept in memory ( if this is what you are referring to ), I'm fine with `read` or any other way, even the constructor of the `vector` class supports iterators, so I'm fine on that side, the "problem" are the iterators themself, I would like to write one to try to browse the data differently. EDIT: I would like to avoid any C-ish way, I'll stick with the iterators.

Comment: *you are basically reading 1 byte at each call* -- from `ifstream`'s in-memory buffer, not from the file itself. The actual read(2) calls are still for every 4k or 16k or whatever is the default buffer for you.

Comment: @Cubbi yes, I wasn't going to introduce the buffered/unbuffered behaviour because I want to keep the focus on the iterators, but you are right, anyway I'm also not interested on this because is something platform-specific and I'm also trying to adopt a solution that is cross-platform as much as possible, without introducing extra stuff. That's why I would like to re-write an iterator, looks like it's the perfect mix between abstraction from the file and portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to optimize `std::copy()` using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` but hardly any implementation does. Just deriving from something won't really do the trick either because that isn't how iterators work.

The most effective built-in approach is probably to simply dump the file into an `std::ostringstream` and the get a `std::string` from there:

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << file.rdbuf();
std::string content = out.str();
```

If you want to avoid travelling through a `std::string` you could write a stream buffer directly dumping the content into a memory area or a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and also using the output operation above.

The `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`s could, in principle have a backdoor to the stream buffer's and bypass characterwise operations. Without that backdoor you won't be able to speed up anything using these iterators. You *could* create an iterator on top of stream buffers using the stream buffer's `sgetn()` to deal with a similar buffer. In that case you'd pretty much need a version of `std::copy()` dealing with segments (i.e., each fill of a buffer) efficiently. Short of either I'd just read the file into buffer using a stream buffer and iterate over that.

Comment: so you are suggesting to basically stick with my first implementation ? What are the possible errors ? What happens if the file is corrupted ?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is not to use a custom stream, stream-buffer or stream-iterator.

```
#include <fstream>

struct Data {
    short a;
    short b;
    int   c;
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& stream, Data& data) {
    static_assert(sizeof(Data) == 2*sizeof(short) + sizeof(int), "Invalid Alignment");
    if(stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(Data))) {
        // Consider endian
    }
    else {
        // Error
    }
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream stream;
    Data data;
    while(stream >> data) {
        // Process
    }
    if(stream.fail()) {
        // Error (EOF is good)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could dare to make a stream buffer iterator reading elements having a bigger
size than the underlaying char_type:

- What if the data has an invalid format ?
- What if the data is incomplete and at EOF ?

The state of the stream is not maintained by the buffer or iterator.

Comment: I can buffer the entire file ?

Comment: @user2485710 That would depend on the underlaying stream buffer (hence it is possible)