# How to create a dynamic array of structs reading data from a binary file

Tags: visual-c++, struct, binaryfiles

I have a `struct` which describes the data objects stored in a binary file. The struct looks like:

```
struct Sum_str {
public:
    char    FINISH_T[24]; // U4
    char    DISP_COD; // C1
    char    USR_DESC[128]; // Cn
    char    EXC_DESC[128]; // Cn
};
```

This is loaded via reading from a binary file and the number of data objects in the file may vary. When I declare the `struct` as a set limit via a `const` everything works. Unfortunately the binary can have less or more data than declared.

How can I dynamically grow the array as needed depending on the number of objects stored in the binary file?

Comment: In the example below using 'Person book[30];' is still a set const value of 30. I want to have a dynamic value knowing that I could have as many as 50000+ but don't want to declare 50000+ as it could be 100000 (never know). I am still looking for the solution. I know programs have done this or there is a good work around.

Comment: If you look at the example using `Person book[30]'` again what you will see is that that array is being used to create a specified number of structs to generate the **output binary file**. The input, which is what you want, is done by reading from the binary file into a `std::vector`. I suggest you take another look at the answer and work through it, both of the source code examples. They both use `std::vector` while one also uses `operator <<` and `operator >>` for I/O.

Comment: I realize you are looking at it from the simplest view/example I could put forth. It does get more complex as it is not just an input output struct. In other forms of the struct(s) the data is calculated for statistical analysis, it is also charted, and for other binary files it is merged. The solution is not to create arrays of the members. Some structs have multiple members and some structs are repeated for example in one case 25000 * 1000 * 25 currently. That is without merging binary files. It seems as though I will have to investigate work arounds.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the posted question, though it is a useful question, is not really your actual question at all? I am unfortunately not a mind reader so the only question that I or anyone else can answer is the question you actually post. If what I have answered provides an answer to your posted question, please do me the curtsy of marking it as an answer. Since this is a useful question, please do not delete it even if my answer is insufficient for the **posted** question. I went to quite a bit of trouble to produce an answer and I don't want to see that time wasted.

Comment: Reading your second comment again, I am not sure that you have actually reviewed the answer I posted. I am curious why you would put a comment concerning my answer in the comments of your posted question rather than the comments of the answer I posted. Please put comments for an answer in the comments section for the answer.

Comment: You may also want to review this material about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct container if the size of your arrays can be greater than your given maxes of 24, 128, 128. Use a vector instead of arrays if you need your containers to be dynamic in size

```
struct Sum_str {
public:
    std::vector<char>    FINISH_T; // U4
    char                 DISP_COD; // C1
    std::vector<char>    USR_DESC; // Cn
    std::vector<char>    EXC_DESC; // Cn
};
```

If you are restricted to the arrays, then only fill the arrays up to their respective lengths. Remember to place null terminating characters in the end of the data so you don't accidentally read past your char arrays when printing the contents. Also use #define for your array sizes instead of magic numbers.

If you are unsure of how many Sum_str structs you need then you should use a container that will fit your requirements. Your requirements require a container that can change in size, therefore you should use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector<Sum_str> my_container;
```

Comment: I am not concerned with the members of the struct. I want to have an array of structs. Sum_str Sum_dat[n]; I cannot have a dynamic arrays of struct as it requires a const for n.

Comment: @SpikeG i'm talking about your inner arrays of your struct Sum_str. you shouldn't be dynamically changing the sizes of those INNER arrays. If you are trying to do so your implementation is incorrect. Use vectors for dynamic size of collection OR only fill the arrays with chars UP TO their respective lengths.

Comment: Not changing the size of the inner members. Those are fairly well known. I just do not know how many instances of the struct I will need.

Comment: I added the last bit that gives you an example of a vector class you can use which can contain any number of structs that you nee, as needed. @SpikeG

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the actual format of the binary file so I am going to assume that it contains an array of the structs you provided.

So your basic algorithm will be something like the following:

- create a `std::vector` of the struct as in `std:vector <Sum_str > myVect;`
- next beginning at the proper point in the binary file, I assume offset 0, read a binary record which means to read in a struct as a binary object
- put it into the vector as in `myVect.push_back(obj);`
- continue this reading of an object and putting into the vector until you reach the proper ending point which I assume is end of file

The primary and dependent assumption is the binary file contains zero or more of what amounts to a binary image of an array of the structures, `Sum_str`. The reason this is important is that you want to make sure that:

- the size of a `Sum_str` object in the file is the same size as a `Sum_str` object in memory
- that the layout and offsets of the members of a `Sum_str` object in the file is the same layout and offsets of members as a `Sum_str` object in memory

If the binary file contains only an array of struct data then you may want to estimate the number of structs contained in the file and create the `std::vector` with an initial capacity that approximates the estimate. See [Initial capacity of vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271017/initial-capacity-of-vector-in-c) as well as [Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file) which provides a way of counting the size of a file. The `tellg()` method of getting the file size is not dependable though it looks like with binary files on Windows and Linux it is close enough.

See [Reading and writing binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file) as well as [How to read a binary file into a vector of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138353/how-to-read-a-binary-file-into-a-vector-of-unsigned-chars) as well as [c++ Read/Write class from/to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038909/c-read-write-class-from-to-binary-file) and [C++ binary files and iterators: getting away with a 1:1 using ifstreambuf_iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128267/c-binary-files-and-iterators-getting-away-with-a-11-using-ifstreambuf-iterat) .

**First cut - a simple demo using older style C++**

I don't have C++11/17 available where I am so here is a version using an older C++ compiler until I can get to a newer version and can do a bit of research.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Person
{
  char name[50];
  int age;
  char phone[24];
};

int mainx()
{
  Person me = {"Robert", 28, "364-2534"};
  Person book[30];
  int x = 123;
  double fx = 34.54;

  // put in some data for our output to show that it works.
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      book[i] = me;
      book[i].age = i *10 + 5;  // modify the age so we can see it changed.
  }
  std::ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("junk.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
  outfile.write((char *)&x, sizeof(int)); // sizeof can take a type
  outfile.write((char *)&fx, sizeof(fx)); // or it can take a variable name
  outfile.write((char *)&me, sizeof(me));
  outfile.write((char *)book, 30*sizeof(Person));
  outfile.close();

  return 0;
}

int mainy()
{
  Person me = {0};
  std::vector<Person>book;
  int x = 0;
  double fx = 0;
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("junk.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
  infile.read((char *)&x, sizeof(int)); // sizeof can take a type
  infile.read((char *)&fx, sizeof(fx)); // or it can take a variable name
  infile.read((char *)&me, sizeof(me));
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      Person buff;
      infile.read((char *)&buff, sizeof(Person));
      book.push_back(buff);
  }

  infile.close();

  std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fx = " << fx << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Person me = " << me.name << ", age " << me.age << ", phone " << me.phone << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    std::cout << "Person book = " << i << "  " << book[i].name << ", age " << book[i].age << ", phone " << book[i].phone << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    mainx();
    mainy();
    return 0;
}
```

**Addendum - demonstrating using iterators**

Here is a second example of the above modified to use iterators. This is not my area of expertise however my testing with Visual Studio 2017 in a console application demonstrates that it works.

See also [istream_iterator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edkb63sw.aspx#istream_iterator__istream_type)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char phone[24];

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& dt);
    friend std::istream& operator<<(std::istream& os, const Person& dt);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& dt)
{
    os.write((char *)&dt, sizeof(Person));
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, const Person& dt)
{
    os.read((char *)&dt, sizeof(Person));
    return os;
}

// construct a binary file that contains various objects.
// in the following routine we will read back out from
// the binary file the objects we wrote into it.
int mainx()
{
    Person me = { "Robert", 28, "364-2534" };
    std::vector<Person> book;
    int x = 123;
    double fx = 34.54;

    // put in some data for our output to show that it works.
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Person x = me;
        x.age = i * 10 + 5;  // modify the age so we can see it changed.

        book.push_back (x);
    }

    // construct out output file with the various objects
    // we want to save. when we read from this file
    // we will want to use the same types of variables
    // in the same order since there is no meta data
    // in this file to indicate object types or object boundaries.
    std::ofstream outfile("junk.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    outfile << x;
    outfile << fx;
    outfile << me;

    // write out the vector of Person objects.
    for (auto x : book) outfile << x;

    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}

// following routine opens the persistent store and reads
// back in the objects that were saved. we need to do
// the reading in the same order they were written.
int mainy()
{
    Person me = { 0 };
    int x = 0;
    double fx = 0;
    std::ifstream infile("junk.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    infile >> x;
    infile >> fx;
    infile >> me;

    // istream_iterator from stream infile
    std::istream_iterator<Person> is(infile);
    // End-of-stream iterator 
    std::istream_iterator<Person> isEof;

    std::vector<Person>book;

    // iterate over the Person objects in the input
    // stream until end of file pushing each object
    // read into our vector.
    while (is != isEof) {
        book.push_back(*is);
        is++;
    }

    infile.close();

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fx = " << fx << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Person me = " << me.name << ", age " << me.age << ", phone " << me.phone << std::endl;

    int i = 0;
    for (auto x : book) {
        i++;
        std::cout << "Person book = " << i << "  " << x.name << ", age " << x.age << ", phone " << x.phone << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    mainx();    // write the binary file
    mainy();    // read the binary file
    return 0;
}
```